# GPU acceleration on AWS p2.xlarge instance does not seem to be working for tensorflow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, tensorflow

So I am having some difficulties getting a CPU accelerated instance to work.

after launching the ec2 instance. I would do the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
wget "http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.168-1_amd64.deb"
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.168-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

So far so good, now running nvidia-smi yields [image: nvidia-smi] which indicates that this installation worked. Now installing nvidia-docker like this also seems to be working:

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add - && \
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) && \
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2 && \
sudo pkill -SIGHUP dockerd
```

This is quickly confirmed by running: `sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda:9.2-base-ubuntu18.04 nvidia-smi`

Now my problem, when running a docker container built on `FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3` it seems like my GPUs are not being used. As indicated by the little check I put in my training script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("GPU Available: ", tf.test.is_gpu_available())
```

This yields a: `GPU Available:  False` when running the container with --runtime=nvidia

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You can try https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B076K31M1S an AMI from nVidia or start from a "Deep learning AMI" at amazon. I am not sure what exactly your problem is, but this should help to bypass most compatibility issues

Comment: @y.selivonchyk this won't work on a p2.xlarge though, will it?

Comment: @y.selivonchyk I tried it for the sake of the argument. Still getting that obnoxious `GPU Available:  False` any ideas how to debug?

Comment: I am not familiar with docker. You may try installing TF-gpu through pip and make sure that it works that way first, if so, there must be an issue with your docker set-up or your custom TF distribution.